# ¿Cómo deserializar un JSONArray con Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, jsonarray

Tengo un campo en una base de datos de Parse.com, que es un array, pero el array que contiene es algo asi:

```
[
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "User",
    "objectId": "AFztrp0BnW"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "User",
    "objectId": "MOclxY7fKZ"
  }
]
```

Entonces pensé que con Retrofit se podía traducir. Pero al ejecutar me da un error que falta la baseUrl, puse una aleatoria pero sigue dando el mismo error.

Mi Fragment

```
private fun getRetrofit()
    {
        val array = user.getJSONArray("favoriteYobers")!! //Trae array com Json
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

        val service = retrofit.create(FavoritesService::class.java)

        val favoritos = service.listFavorites(array)

        favoritos.enqueue(object : Callback<List<FavoriteItem>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<FavoriteItem>>,
                response: Response<List<FavoriteItem>>
            ) {
                response.body()?.let { favoritos ->
                    (binding.yobersFavoritosRecyclerView.adapter as FavoritosAdapter).setData(favoritos)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<FavoriteItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                call.cancel()
            }

        })
    }
```

La interface

```
interface FavoritesService
{
    @GET
    fun listFavorites(@Body list : JSONArray) : Call<List<FavoriteItem>>
}
```

y mi data class

```
data class FavoriteItem(
    val __type: String,
    val className: String,
    val objectId: String
)
```

Comment: La pregunta no tiene sentido. La url es necesaria para indicar a dónde enviar las peticiones HTTP. Tampoco tiene sentido que una petición GET tenga body.  Por favor, explica mejor lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Tengo un campo en una base de datos de Parse.com, que es un array, pero el array que contiene es algo asi: [
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "User",
    "objectId": "AFztrp0BnW"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "User",
    "objectId": "MOclxY7fKZ"
  }
]   // Entonces pensé que con Retrofit se podía traducir ya que el campo se trae desde un getJsonArray y trae el array así completo, no encuentro solucion de como traducirlo para que me de solo los valores de esas variable. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: varios malentedidos. espero que mi respuesta te ayude a aclarar los conceptos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias librerias para parsear JSONs pero definitavemente Retrofit no es una de ellas. **Retrofit es un cliente http**, es decir que su función es hacer peticiones http a una url y recibir las respuestas. Supongo que el malentendido surge porque retrofit además tiene la capacidad de comunicarse con una librería de serialización a través del converter que le pasas al método `addConverterFactory()`. En tu caso le pasaste `GsonConverterFactory` por lo que la deserialización se haría con la librería [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). Pero tu ya tienes el json en memoria. Retrofit **no tiene nada que hacer aquí!** Elimina todo el código relacionado y  **usa Gson directamente**.
Hago el ejemplo con Gson porque ya lo tienes en tus dependencias pero ten en cuenta que hay mejores alternativas.

```
val json = user.getJSONArray("favoriteYobers").toString()
val favoritos = Gson().fromJson<List<FavoriteItem>>(
    json,
    (object: TypeToken<List<FavoriteItem>>(){}).type
 )
(binding.yobersFavoritosRecyclerView.adapter as FavoritosAdapter).setData(favoritos)
```

Lo sé, la sintaxis es bastante fea pero así es como funciona. Si usaras, por ejemplo, la librería oficial [kotlinx.serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html), se reduciría a esto

```
val favoritos = Json.decodeFromString<List<FavoriteItem>>(json)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias eso mismo era lo que necesitaba, te lo agradezco mucho de verdad.